# QFontMetrics returns inaccurate results

Tags: c++, qt, fontmetrics

I have a custom delegate in my `QTableWidget` to hightlight matches if a user searches something. Unfortunately the rectangle position does often not really fit This happens on some characters or phrases or depending on the number of matches or the size of the leading string. I can't find something specific causing this. Here is one example: [image: Example].

This is my paint routine (a bit messy from all the trial and error trying to fix the issue):

```
void custom_delegate::paint(QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const{

    const QTableWidget* table_widget = qobject_cast<const QTableWidget*>(qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionViewItemV3*>(&option)->widget);
    const int cell_width = table_widget->columnWidth(index.column());

    // basic table cell rectangle
    QRect rect_a = option.rect;

    // adjust rectangle to match text begin
    QStyle* style;
    if(table_widget != 0){
        style = table_widget->style();
    }else{
        style = QApplication::style();
    }
    const int text_horizontal_margin = style->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_FocusFrameHMargin, 0, table_widget) + 1;
    QRect rect_b = rect_a.adjusted(text_horizontal_margin, 0, -text_horizontal_margin, 0);

    // adjust rectangle to match text height
    QFont cell_font = index.model()->data(index, Qt::FontRole).value<QFont>();
    cell_font.setPointSize(9);
    QFontMetrics fm(cell_font);
    const int height = fm.height();

    rect_b.setY(rect_a.y() + (rect_a.height() - height)/2);
    rect_b.setHeight(height);

    // displayed text
    std::string cell_text = qstrtostr(fm.elidedText(index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString(),Qt::ElideRight,rect_a.width()));
    int found_pos = find_ci(cell_text, this->filter_string, 0);
    int old_pos = 0;
    int found_width = 0;
    QRect rect_c = rect_b;

    // find occurence of filter string in cell_text
    while(found_pos != std::string::npos){

        std::string front = cell_text.substr(0, found_pos);
        rect_c.setX(rect_b.x() + fm.tightBoundingRect(QString::fromStdString(front)).width());
        rect_c.setWidth(fm.width(QString::fromStdString(cell_text.substr(found_pos, this->filter_string.size()))));
        painter->fillRect(rect_c, Qt::yellow);
        old_pos = found_pos+1;
        found_pos = find_ci(cell_text, this->filter_string, old_pos);
    }
}
```

**Notes:** `filter_string` is the string searched for, `find_ci` is just a wrapper for `std::string::find` including case-insensitivity but not important here as this test case is fully lower-case and I use `std::string` for non-qt stuff.

**Edit:** For the width calculation I tried `fm.tightBoundingRect().width()`, `fm.boundingRect.width()` and `fm.width()` with different but never correct results.

I use Qt 5.2

Comment: Have you tried to pass `painter.device()` to `QFontMetrics` constructor?

Comment: @BartoszKP I did not but unfortunately it did not change anything. But it lead me to trying `QFontMetrics fm(painter->font());` which (together with `fm.width()` instead of the other two) procudes a result with only a constant offset of 1px in any cases! Thanks a lot for leading me to this so if you want to take the credit I'll gladly accept it

Comment: `QFontMetrics fm(painter->font());` (with `fm.horizontalAdvance()` (replaces `width()`)) solves the exact same problem for me!

Answer (score 5):

In my case I got the desired result with the following hack:

```
auto initialRect = fm.boundingRect(text);
auto improvedRect = fm.boundingRect(initialRect, 0, text);
```

It's not entirely clear why the [other overload of `boundingRect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfontmetrics.html#boundingRect-6) returns the correct result, but it may be just accidental, because as the documentation states:

> The bounding rectangle returned by this function is somewhat larger than that calculated by the simpler `boundingRect()` function. This function uses the maximum left and right font bearings as is necessary for multi-line text to align correctly. Also, `fontHeight()` and `lineSpacing()` are used to calculate the height, rather than individual character heights.

The [`width`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfontmetrics.html#width) method you propose also will return larger result, but it does not seem correct, as it should be used only when you need a position for a next word:

> [...] `width()` returns the distance to where the next string should be drawn.

Also, sometimes it matters whether you pass the result of `painter.device()` to `QFontMetrics` constructor.